# C++ classes, help needed

Tags: c++, class, opencv, class-constructors

I am new to C++ and trying to understand a code related to OpenCV. It has a class as follow:

```
class Settings
{
public:
    Settings() : goodInput(false) {}
    enum Pattern { NOT_EXISTING, CHESSBOARD, CIRCLES_GRID, ASYMMETRIC_CIRCLES_GRID };
    enum InputType { INVALID, CAMERA, VIDEO_FILE, IMAGE_LIST };
.
.
.
.
}
```

what does `Settings() : goodInput(false) {}` means here. I don't think it is a constructor. Explain this please.

Comment: it is an empty inline constructor {} with an initializer list (but only one element)

Comment: I hope there's a `bool goodInput` in the class somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is indeed a constructor. What you see after `:` is called *initializer-list* and it initializes values before entering the curly brackets.

You should also know that member variables of a class are **always** initialized before entering the constructor body. If you don't mention a member variable in the initializer list, it will be default initialized.

Comment: how to initialize more than one variables in this way?

Comment: @AmeerHamza `Settings() : goodInput(false), otherVariable(true) {}`

Answer (score 0):

It assigns the (default) initial value `false` to the member (probably) checking the validity of the input.